# Matplotlib: How to reduce the spacing of 2 bars in bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bar chart with only 2 bar data.
How can I make the bar plotted in the centre area? (The current bar spacing are too wide).
More specifically, how can I let the bar plot at the centre area instead of spread into the edge area if next time I have 2,3,4 or 5.... bar data?

The current plotting is based on following:

```
legend_name=['Calcite-PAM 25/40', 'Calcite-PAM 25/80']
# enter code here`
x = np.arange(len(legend_name))                                               
plt.bar(x,average_y,width=0.2,align='center')                                                                            
plt.errorbar(x,average_y, yerr=err, fmt="o", color="b",linewidth=1, elinewidth=0.5, capsize=2)
```

[image: Bar plot]

Comment: You could either increase the widths of the bars (e.g. `plt.bar(..., width=0.8`), or increase the margins (e.g. `plt.margins(x=0.3)`).

Comment: \i the bar become way too thick which is kinda ugly..... I want to maintain same bar width but put them closer ...

Comment: but the plt.margin works! Thanks :)